# How can this c++ function return anything?

Tags: c++, function, return

The following function does not have a "return grade", only return 0, yet it works  and returns grade perfectly. How can this be?

```
int Grade(double points)
{
    int grade = floor(0.25*points - 1.5);
    if (grade < 0)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *prog.cpp:3:5: error: ‘grade’ was not declared in this scope*

Comment: unrefined behavior

Comment: @bolov - Best typo ever :)

Comment: Just because it compiles, doesn't mean it works. My compiler says: "warning: control reaches end of non-void function". I recommend you turn up the warning level of the compiler.

Comment: You should have a `return grade;` statement after the `if` statement.

Comment: BTW, you have an evil coding style.  Variable and function names should differ by more than case.  This helps resolve typos.

Answer (score 5):

> How can this be?

Either the function returns 0, when `grade` is less than zero (after modification), or the behaviour of the program is undefined when `grade` is not less than zero. If function returns non-void, then it must not end without a return expression, or there will be UB.

Answer (score 2):

Having a code path which does not return a value is clearly undefined behavior here, so the question is how can undefined behavior possibly return the correct value here? Presumably, there ought to be a `return grade;` at the end of the function.

One possibility is how values are returned from a function. On x86 systems, an int return value would typically be placed in the EAX register before the function returned. Other architectures may use different register names, but putting a return value in a register is pretty common.

It's likely that the line which computes the value of `grade` in the first place left the value of `grade` in the EAX register. Or, perhaps, the line which compares `grade` to 0 loads it into the EAX register. In either case, when the function returns, it would happen to have the correct value in EAX. If you really want to know what it's doing, have the compiler generate an assembly listing or step through the code with a debugger at the assembly language level.

Undefined behavior means the code can technically do anything. Which means that sometimes it does the (apparently) right thing.